# How can I create a function that push objects in an existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have been trying to create a function with 4 parameters that allows me to push an object in an existing array. However, I am not getting the result I want. For example, this is the existing array:

```
const firstGen = [
    {name: 'Mewtwo', hp: 110, type: 'physic'},
    {name: 'Charizard', hp: 135, type: 'flying'},
    {name: 'Pikachu', hp: 85, type: 'electric'},
    {name: 'Totodile', hp: 55, type: 'water'},
    {name: 'Bayleef', hp: 80, type: 'grass'},
    {name: 'Typlosion', hp: 125, type: 'fire'}
]
```

And this is the function I have created:

```
const addPokemon = (pokedex, pokemonName, pokemonHp, pokemonType) => {
    pokedex.push({pokemonName,pokemonHp, pokemonType})
}
```

Example input:

```
addPokemon(secondGen, 'Lucario', 85, 'fighting')
```

But the output is:

```
  { name: 'Mew', hp: 110, type: 'physic' },
  { name: 'Arcanine', hp: 135, type: 'Fire' },
  { name: 'Raikou', hp: 140, type: 'electric' },
  { name: 'Blastoise', hp: 120, type: 'water' },
  { name: 'Gardevoir', hp: 100, type: 'grass' },
  { name: 'Scorbunny', hp: 45, type: 'fire' },
  { pokemonName: 'Lucario', pokemonHp: 85, pokemonType: 'fighting' }
```

As you can see, the parameters that I have in my function also appear in the output and not the property names of my array. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the key names you want in your object: `{name: pokemonName, hp: pokemonHp, type: pokemonType}`.

Comment: `{pokemonName,pokemonHp, pokemonType}` is shorthand for `{pokemonName: pokemonName, pokemonHp: pokemonHp, pokemonType: pokemonType}` - there is no way for JS to guess you want different names for these properties, so you just have to do it manually: `{name: pokemonName, hp: pokemonHp, type: pokemonType}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this part of the code

```
pokedex.push({pokemonName,pokemonHp, pokemonType})
```

is actually a shorthand for

```
pokedex.push({pokemonName: pokemonName,pokemonHp: pokemonHp, pokemonType: pokemonType})
```

This notation is used when the variable name and the attribute have the same name. In your case you need to specify the attribute manually by doing:

```
pokedex.push({name: pokemonName, hp: pokemonHp, type: pokemonType})
```

Or changing the parameters to be:

```
const addPokemon = (pokedex, name, hp, type) => {
    pokedex.push({name, hp, type})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the ES6 object shorthand, where `{ foo }` is short for `{ foo: foo }`. So the object literal

```
{pokemonName,pokemonHp, pokemonType}
```

is equivalent to

```
{pokemonName: pokemonName, pokemonHp: pokemonHp, pokemonType: pokemonType}
```

You need to use the property names that you really want.

```
pokedex.push({name: pokemonName, hp:pokemonHp, type: pokemonType})
```

Or you could change the names of the function parameters to match the properties.

```
const addPokemon = (pokedex, name, hp, type) => {
    pokedex.push({name, hp, type})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating new properties in the objects that you are pushing instead of assigning the inputs to existing properties.

You have two options:

1. Explicitly set the property:

```js
const addPokemon = (pokedex, pokemonName, pokemonHp, pokemonType) => {
    pokedex.push({ name: pokemonName,
                   hp: pokemonHp, 
                   type: pokemonType});

}
```

2. Change the parameter names to match the properties (less typing that way):

```js
const addPokemon = (pokedex, name, hp, type) => {
    pokedex.push({ name, hp, type});
}
```

this is identical to:

```js
const addPokemon = (pokedex, name, hp, type) => {
    pokedex.push({name: name, hp: hp, type: type})
}
```